# Oracle Linux 6 download files?

Tags: linux, oracle-10g

I want to download Oracle Linux 6 for basic use to install on my laptop to use oracle 11g r2 database since this is one of only few Linux distros which is supported. When I go to the downloads section I these are the options:

```
-Oracle Linux Release 6 Update 4 for x86_64 (64 Bit)
-Oracle Linux Release 6 Update 4 Boot iso image for x86_64 (64 bit)
-Oracle Linux Release 6 Update 4 UEK Boot ISO image for x86_64 (64 bit)
-Oracle Linux Release 6 Update 4 source DVD 1
-Oracle Linux Release 6 Update 4 source DVD 2
```

I want to just burn it onto a DVD and then install it on my laptop so which is the right download(s) I need? As well I know UEK is the unbreakable kernel but is this mandatory to install or optional? Normally I would download them all and try, but I am very limited on my bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

For a full install you want to choose Oracle Linux Release 6 Update 4 for x86_64 (64 Bit). The boot isos are minimal installations and the source isos are for compiling it from source and to comply with GPL.

Comment: And Uek is optional, you can switch between the kernels with yum.